# How do you add to tooltip, a series in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to use a series as extra info, so when the user hover on the point, the tooltip will display the extra series

Example of file:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
X1,X2,X3,X4
```

I have #1 on X and #2 on Y, and would like #3 only in the tooltip.

How do you tell the tooltip about that series? I know how to use this.x and this.y, but the series is not on either axis; is saved in a different array

Comment: which tooltip option are you referring, please provide a link to its documentation on Higcharts api reference

Comment: You need to use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) to customise content of tooltip, or use [shared](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) option to display values from other series.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the example from the site; it uses this.x and this.y, but my series is nether on x or y. I load data dynamically and store it in arrays, so I need a way to tell the tooltip to grab a specific array that contains the series, and then while I move the mouse, it needs to sync it with what is on the plot, so X1 will be displayed at point a, X2 at point b and so on. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

Comment: So please replicate your example as live with your data, because in this example it works properly.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, Rob was faster than me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/PAM3K/

```
$(function () {
    var myOtherData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
    $('#container').highcharts({

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return 'The value for <b>myOtherData</b> is: ' + myOtherData[this.point.x];
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }, {
            data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for showing the function! So the trick is that you can load any data array, and for the position you set the this.x, so it always know where the pointer is hovering upon. Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes that's basically it 